# PyQT render on top of another running application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm very new to PyQT and was trying to find if I could render on top of another (third party non QT) application.

For example say I wanted to render my QT app over an application is there any way I could get the current window(s) location & dimensions and z-index (excuse me if that's not the right term) and render my QT app above that?

Comment: Have you tried using something like `widget->mapToGlobal( widget->pos() )` ? Perhaps read this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/application-windows.html

Comment: I know that you can embed outside sources into a qt app by passing out the widgets window id handle. But I am not sure if you can use pyqt to draw to arbitrary system window ids.  @Kush: That is just for mapping a point from local widget coordinates to global coordinates.